# SLAT (EPT) support issue

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5

I need SLAT support to use Windows Phone 8 Emulator on my PC, and so I need to buy a new laptop to get it running.

I've searched for Intel, and found that all i3 - 5 - 7 series support SLAT. I've also found a laptop with Intel Core i5 3210M, and searched specifically if this CPU supports SLAT (EPT). I'm told yes, virtualization is supported.

Finally I bought this laptop, but it seems it doesn't have SLAT support - at least by looking at "coreinfo" program output. I can't enable HYPER-V feature - I'm getting an message saying that "your CPU does not support this feature". (I'm using Windows 8 Enterprise 64 bit which is greater than PRO).

I've also looked at my BIOS config, but couldn't find any setting to enable or disable these features. (My bios seem to be very incomprehensive.)

So is there any possibility that in laptop factory, engineers said "lets do not put SLAT support for this laptop, I'm a little bit tired, and wanna go home"?

What should I do? A BIOS update?

Here is my laptop specs. That may be relevant for SLAT(EPT):

- Intel Core i5 3210M - 2.5 GHz
- Windows 8 Enterprise 64 bit
- Packard Bell Easynote TE11 - HC - 604TK

According to all checks made on internet;

- Checked Intel's web page and seems SUPPORTED
- Used a tool which is given on Microsoft's page made by a software team, seems SUPPORTED
- Used a tool of Intel and seems, SUPPORTED

Except;

- Coreinfo says there is no support

I think it raises from BIOS specifications, but I dont have some kind of professional BIOS, my BIOS was programmed for dummies to switch simple things, not more.

Any advises? is there any professional BIOS to embed into my BIOS chip?

Comment: What says  "coreinfo -v" ? BTW, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14170039/1758762 I'm surprised, i5 looks very good

Comment: @duDE coreinfo -v tells me you don't have any of them. I think I need to upgrade my BIOS as it seems very non-detailed. It nearly contains only boot order and some system informations, not more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely related with your BIOS. Try to replace an official BIOS provided by your manufacturer. Your BIOS may be very simple, but some BIOS upgrades may enable your Virtualization as default where your BIOS looks the same again with no advanced options.

Here is another information: Microsoft's coreinfo tool speaks to you what it sees, that is, If you SLAT is disabled in your BIOS, coreinfo will tell you that inability of any virtualization.

To avoid of this, and to see if your CPU supports SLAT (Virtualization), firstly check Intel's or AMD's webpage. Then use Intel Processor Identification Tool to see if VT-x is supported or not.